# Settings window too large in Python IDLE 3.8

Tags: python, python-idle

I am trying to increase the font size of my code on IDLE 3.8. For this I go on IDLE->Preferences->Fonts/Tabs and change from there. But the length of my settings window is by default quite large so the OK/Apply buttons are not visible and I can't save any changes to the font size.

Is there a way I can either reduce the size of window or any alternate way to increase font? I am using macOS version 10.13.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.8 is over 5 years old.  I had the same problem on my macBook Air. So I added a new page to the settings dialog and rearranged things to make the dialog shorter.  If you cannot upgrade to 3.11 or 3.12, here are 2 things you can do.

1. In not already, move the dock to one side instead of top/bottom to have more vertical room.  I did this on my macBook Air.
2. Start Terminal in your home directory.  Enter `ls -a` to confirm the presence of `.idlerc`.  `cd .idlerc`.  `ls` and find `config-main.cfg`.  Edit that file.  If nothing else, enter `idle3 config-main.cfg`.  Change the font-size there.  Be careful not to add noise to the file.  Save.

Comment: Simply updating the IDLE version worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Could you accept the answer then?

Answer (score 0):

I just opened IDLE 3.10 on Windows and everything works well. I looked at the IDLE Doc from the Help menu and it says this:

> Configure IDLE:
> Open a configuration dialog and change preferences for the following: fonts, indentation, keybindings, text color themes, startup windows and size, additional help sources, and extensions.  **On macOS, open the configuration dialog by selecting Preferences in the application menu. For more details, see Setting preferences under Help and preferences.**

However, I'm curious to know why you'd prefer IDLE. There are many great text editors out there for Python. **VSCode** is a great choice for experienced users whilst **Sublime Text** is Beginner friendly.

Comment: Promoting and demoting the virtue of different editors is exlicitly off-topic since it leads to often heated discusssions of personal opinions and relative weightings of different features.